# Rのヒートマップ

Tags: r

Rで氏名、国語、社会、数学、理科、英語の変数からなるデータをheatmap関数でヒートマップにします。氏名は文字型、各科目は得点ですので、数値です。
その際に氏名、科目でクラスターリングされますが、氏名が400名にも及ぶので、どのクラスターに誰が含まれているかが細かすぎて見えません。
クラスタリングされた結果（ヒートマップではなく、どの人とどの人がクラスタリングされているかの情報）をテキストファイルに書き出せないものでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

中で動いているのは`hclust()`という関数です。

このあたりに解説があります。
http://sugisugirrr.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/10/10/%E7%AC%AC%EF%BC%96%EF%BC%91%E5%9B%9E_%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E5%88%86%E6%9E%90

例えば、

```
set.seed(11)
dat <- matrix(sample(1:100, 30, replace = T), 10)

heatmap(dat)
```

こんなデータで、列側のクラスタは、

```
dat_clust <- hclust(dist(dat))
plot(dat_clust, hang = -1)
```

これと同値になります。

例えば高さ50以下のクラスタの構成は、

```
dat_clust$merge[dat_clust$height < 50, ]
```

この結果の読み方は↑のURLに書いてあります。